# how to make group by and orderby linq

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework

This is my model:

```
public partial class DEGIVREUSE_SITE 
{
    public int EVENEMENT_ID { get; set; }
    public string DEGIVREUSE_ID { get; set; }
    public string SITE_COD { get; set; }
    public string ETAT_GLOBAL { get; set; }
    public string ETAT_CARBURANT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> KM_CHASSIS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HEURE_CHASSIS { get; set; }
    public string ETAT_FONCTIONNEMENT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HEURE_GROUPE { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTAIRE { get; set; }
    public virtual DEGIVREUSE DEGIVREUSE { get; set; }
    public virtual SITE SITE { get; set; }
    public virtual EVENEMENT EVENEMENT { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class InventaireDegivreuse : Evenement
{
    public InventaireDegivreuse()
        : base(-1, Global.EvenementType.InventaireDegivreuse, DateTime.MinValue)
    {
    }

    public InventaireDegivreuse(int id, DateTime date, string libelle, string societe)
        : base(id, (int)Global.EvenementType.InventaireDegivreuse, date, libelle, "", "", societe)
    {
        ListeDegivreuses = new List<EtatDegivreuse>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<EtatDegivreuse> ListeDegivreuses { get; set; }

    public void AddDegivreuse(EtatDegivreuse degivreuse)
    {
        lock (ListeDegivreuses)
            ListeDegivreuses.Add(degivreuse);
    }

    public int NbDegivreuses
    {
        get
        {
            lock (ListeDegivreuses)
                return ListeDegivreuses.Count;
        }
    }

    public override void GenereLibelle()
    {
        Libelle = Properties.Resources.InventaireDegivreuse.Replace("%s", SocieteNom);
    }
}
```

I need to orderby all Events with EVENEMENT_DT_CREA and after for each societe i get the first element of InventaireDegivreuse (the newer one which has the biggest EVENEMENT_DT_CREA)  , I try this query but i had a bad result:

```
   var @eventss = GetQuery(unitOfWork).Include(entity => entity.EVENEMENT).OrderByDescending(e => e.EVENEMENT.EVENEMENT_DT_CREA).GroupBy(m => m.EVENEMENT.SOCIETE_NOM).First().ToList();
```

In my solution for only one societe, i have correct result like this:

```
  public InventaireDegivreuse GetLastBySociete(IReadOnlyUnitOfWork unitOfWork, string societeName)
    {
        var @event = GetQuery(unitOfWork).Include(entity => entity.EVENEMENT).OrderByDescending(e => e.EVENEMENT.EVENEMENT_DT_CREA).FirstOrDefault(m => m.EVENEMENT.SOCIETE_NOM ==societeName);
        return DatabaseMapping.Map<DEGIVREUSE_SITE, InventaireDegivreuse>(@event);
    }
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Could you please translate to English?  I know it theoretically shouldn't matter but it's easier to follow what's going on with English identifiers.

Comment: Also, when you say "I had a bad result", could you be more explicit about 1) what you expected to see and 2) what you actually got?

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to decide what do you want but I suspect that you want something like this:

```
var @event = GetQuery(unitOfWork)
          .Include(entity => entity.EVENEMENT)
          .GroupBy(e => e.EVENEMENT.SOCIETE_NOM)
          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.EVENEMENT.EVENEMENT_DT_CREA)
                        .First());
```

Comment: I try your solution but I have an error : Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 ne prend pas en charge APPLY

Comment: the problem of oracle is du to first when i delete first there's no problem, how can i resolve this

Comment: Try to use `FirstOrDefault()` instead.

Comment: same problem with FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I've translated the "ne prend pas en charge APPLY" and made conclusion that dis solution can't work for Oracle. Although, the query provider have to make appropriate translation.